Solving Series of Equations with Minimum Function
I am trying to solve a large series of equations, but struggling to understand how to convert a minimum function into the matrix. Below is an excerpt of 6 equations from the series of 252 (where $c_1, c_3, c_5$ denote different nodes and $L^{c_1}$ and $C_n^{c_1}$ are constants).
$$
{1.25C}_d^{c_1}\ =\ C_n^{c_1} \\
0.5C_d^{c_1}\ -\ C_r^{c_1}=\ 0 \\
C_d^{c_1}\ -\ C_r^{c_1}\ -\ C_o^{c_1}\ =\ 0 \\
C_o^{c_1}\ -\ C_h^{c_1}=\ L^{c_1} \\
{min(C}_h^{c_1},\ C_h^{c_3},\ C_h^{c_5})\ -\ C_a^{c_1} =\ 0 \\
C_h^{c_1}\ -\ C_a^{c_1}\ -\ C_s^{c_1}=0
$$
My first attempt at converting this to a matrix is:
$$
\left[\begin{matrix}1.25&0&0&0&0&0\\0.5&-1&0&0&0&0\\1&-1&-1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&-1&0&0\\&&&&&\\0&0&0&1&-1&-1\\\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}C_d^{c_1}\\C_r^{c_1}\\C_o^{c_1}\\C_h^{c_1}\\C_a^{c_1}\\C_s^{c_1}\\\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}C_n^{c_1}\\0\\0\\L^{c_1}\\0\\0\\\end{matrix}\right]
$$
Is it possible to translate the equation with the minimum function in it into the matrix?
